# compare and sort tuples in python

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

The problem I have is difficult to describe in general, so I describe the actual problem.

I have points in an image, which have a specific ID. Additionally, I have a larger amount of points in another image, some of which having the same ID. I want to link to the points in the first image. Linking should be over the position in the tuple. `ID1` doesn't not have to be in position 1, but the corresponding points should be the same position in both tuples.

```
ID1 = (1, 2, 3, 4)
ID2 = (5, 3, 1, 2, 4)

points1= ((1,2), (1, 4), (3,5), (7,8))
points2= ((1,3), (2, 4), (2,5), (4,8), (3,9))
```

What I need is a sorted output like the following

```
points_1_outpout = ((1,2), (1, 4), (3,5), (7,8))
points_2_output =  ((2,5), (4, 8), (2,4), (3,9))
```

What I did was: (and it is ugly and not really working, because I can't expect to have increasing IDs without "holes")

```
import numpy as np

ID1 = (1, 2, 3, 4)
ID2 = (5, 3, 1, 2, 4)

ID1 = np.asarray(ID1)
Id2 = np.asarray(ID2)

points1= ((1,2), (1, 4), (3,5), (7,8))
points2= ((1,3), (2, 4), (2,5), (4,8), (3,9))


points1 = np.asarray(points1)
points2 = np.asarray(points2)

##points_1_outpout = ((1,2), (1, 4), (3,5), (7,8))
###points_2_output =  ((2,5), (4, 8), (2,4), (3,9))

ID1sort, Corner1sort = zip(*sorted(zip(ID1, points1)))
ID2sort, Corner2sort = zip(*sorted(zip(ID2, points2)))
```

Comment: In what way is the expected output "sorted"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not optimal but you can do:

```
d1 = dict(sorted(zip(ID1, points1)))
d2 = dict(sorted(zip(ID2, points2)))
keys = set(d1).intersection(d2)
out1 = [v for k, v in d1.items() if k in keys]
out2 = [v for k, v in d2.items() if k in keys]
```

Output:

```
>>> out1
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5), (7, 8)]

>>> out2
[(2, 5), (4, 8), (2, 4), (3, 9)]
```

If you use `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

sr1 = pd.Series(points1, index=ID1, name='P1')
sr2 = pd.Series(points2, index=ID2, name='P2')
out = pd.concat([sr1, sr2], axis=1).dropna().to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
{'P1': [(1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5), (7, 8)],
 'P2': [(2, 5), (4, 8), (2, 4), (3, 9)]}
```

Comment: Is the *key* parameter to *sorted()* necessary?

Comment: You are right. My first idea was to use the tuple as key and ID has value... So stupid :)

Comment: in this scenario above, it might not be necessary, but actually this is exactly what i need. If i have ```[1,3,5,6] and [1,5,6]``` sorting alone does not do the trick. I undestand your code and the intersection method was the missing piece, thx again

Answer (score 0):

```
ID1 = (1, 2, 3, 4)
ID2 = (5, 3, 1, 2, 4)

points1 = ((1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5), (7, 8))
points2 = ((1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (4, 8), (3, 9))


def resolve(ids, points):
    return tuple(map(lambda x: x[1], sorted(zip(ids, points))))
 
 
print(resolve(ID1, points1))
print(resolve(ID2, points2))
```

You can use `zip` to match ids with points, and then allow tuple sorting to sort them correctly.

The mapping is used to remove the order IDs for the output.